# ko.applyBindingsToNode vs. ko.applyBindingsToDescendants

Tags: knockout.js

Both functions allow to replace/modify binding context and apply it to unbound nodes. "Unbound" means that my own custom bindings that want to use these useful functions **must** always return `{ controlsDescendantNodes: true }` in `init` function.

So I cannot understand what the difference between them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When using `ko.applyBindingsToNode` or in 3.0 `ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode` you are able to directly supply the bindings that you want to use for a specific element (so, it would not care about `data-bind`).

When calling `ko.applyBindingsToDecendants` you would be applying the bindings that already exist on the child elements (in `data-bind` attributes by default) of the supplied root node.

Comment: Thank, Ryan. In other words: `ko.applyBindingsToNode` applies a set of bindings to the node, but `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` applies a context. So node's context  doesn't relate to bindings applied. "Context" relates to a viewmodel or to a piece of data with some extra properties ($root, $parent and so on). "Bindings" relates to node's links to that data. Right?

Comment: right- except `ko.applyBindingsToNode` can also accept a context, if necessary.  Otherwise, right.